# How can use Selenium to acquire information from this site?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

My spider has past this [test](https://intoli.com/blog/not-possible-to-block-chrome-headless/chrome-headless-test.html),however it still can be detected by this [site](https://vipreader.qidian.com/chapter/1209977/24594895/).
This is my code.

```
import subprocess

from selenium import webdriver

subprocess.Popen('"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --no-sandbox --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.7113.93 Safari/537.36"')

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:14527")

options.add_argument("disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

options.add_argument('user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.7113.93 Safari/537.36"')

options = setChrome()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

[What I see with selenium](https://pic3.zhimg.com/v2-edb5b13ad5383a128bd03b88f48a07ee_b.png)

[What I want to see with selenium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sq38X.png)
I hope [the site](https://vipreader.qidian.com/chapter/1209977/24594895/)regard me as a human when I am using selenium

Comment: You might try using [Selenium-Profiles](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles) or undetected-chromedriver